# Why does github label double ampersands in red? (Javascript)

Tags: github

Doing some code review recently, I spotted that Github is labelling a double ampersand in JS code with a dark red background...

[image]

Does anyone know why this is? What is Github telling us? Should we be writing the code differently?

Comment: Don't know why github marks this, but I can assure you, that this is OK. Moreover, JavaScript does not support "and" keyword unlike most of other languages, so you have really no choice than use &&.

Comment: Is this in a Javascript file or is the Javascript embedded in an HTML file. Bonus: if the code is public, post the link to Github.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth It's in a js file with ruby injection (.js.erb) in a Ruby on Rails ap. This part does not have any ruby injection.